# how to use comboboxes in if statements

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I am working on this program were you can fill in how much surface you need and which colour you want and then you get a recipe of the colour. But I am having one little problem with the combobox to choose the colour and I can´t seem to fix it, can somebody please help me. This is the code I made(I'm pretty new to vba)

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Colour1"
        .AddItem "Colour2"
        .AddItem "Colour3"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    X = TextBox1.Text
    Range("B2") = X

    Range("B9").Value = A
    Range("B10").Value = B

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_Change()

    If ComboBox1.Text = "Colour1" Then
        A = 3 And B = 5

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Colour2" Then
        A = 7 And B = 6

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Colour3" Then
        A = 4 And B = 8

    End If

End Sub
```

And for some reason the part were I made the if-statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I see.

Your `ComboBox_Change` needs to be `ComboBox1_Change` so you are not referencing the correct `ComboBox`.

You are assigning a `string` to an `Integer` variable. You should rather `Dim X as String`.

If you want to the `A` and `B` variables to be available in all Subs for that Module then you need to use `Public A and Integer`. Otherwise there will be no values in `A` and `B`.

You will also need to reference the `Sheet` in which the `Range("B9")` and `Range("B10")`. So if it is in *sheet1* then `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B9")`.

See revised code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public X As String
Public A As Long
Public B As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Colour1"
        .AddItem "Colour2"
        .AddItem "Colour3"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    X = TextBox1.Text
    Range("B2") = X

    Sheet1.Range("B9").Value = A
    Sheet1.Range("B10").Value = B

End Sub
' added the 1 to make it ComboBox1 which is the correct reference
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    If ComboBox1.Text = "Colour1" Then 
        'You can use And when assigning Variables values
        'You need to do it seperately.
        A = 3
        B = 5

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Colour2" Then
        A = 7
        B = 6

    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Colour3" Then
        A = 4
        B = 8

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I see... now i changed it but I still have the problem that Range("B9") and Range("B10") won't change to the value it would give them

Comment: See my edit @justin. You should also reference the `Sheet` when using `Range()` otherwise it will either give an error or use the `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @justin just check my answer again

Comment: But I still keep the problem I think I'm just not looking at the right thing or something. This is what I have right now.

Comment: I am going to try that

Comment: @justin I am glad you came right. Remember to mark the answer you find correct and then to up vote them as well.